# C++ class extension technology

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, yacc

I know the official answer for "extension class in C++ like objective-C or c#" is NO. But is there any hack ways to implement this? And what is the cost?

I ask this because my colleague use my parser to generate C++ class files from a special format txt file. They complained that it is difficult to extension the class.

I can't force them to use inheritance, because the class generated is like this:

```
class A {} 

class B : A {}
```

if my colleague extends A like this:

```
class C : A {}
```

then the B class will not benefit from the C class. That means: In our situation, if `class C : A`, B is meant to inherit from A, then now B should inherit from C now. But it is not possible since the B has hard code to inherit from A. That means, inheritance is not a good option, the truly demand is to extend A.

And using A as a member in a new class is not an option, either. Since our logic is more like a "is-A", not a "has-A", force make A as a member will make the code hard to read.

Currently they directly modify the class header file, and any new member functions is implement in a new cpp file(thanks to C++ class file structure), so if the class changes, the origin cpp file will regenered, they won't care about it, while they use git to merge the new generated header file to the file they have modified.

I can write a parser to scan the header file and do the merge, but  write a parser to fully implement C++ standard BNF(http://www.externsoft.ch/download/cpp-iso.html) is difficult.

Currently I decide to use macros, like the mechanism used by flex and bison to replace the action in .y file to the generated c file. But I wondered if there's a easy way.

Comment: _`class A : C` .. then the B class will not benefit from the C class._ .. What? What about `class A : public C` (or `class A : public virtual C` for good measure)?

Comment: @txtechhelp, that is a mistake, I have re-edit it. Thanks for reading.

Comment: What if another colleague extends `class D: public A`? Multiple inheritance does allow `class B : public C, public D` but this seems like a problem for which no technical solution _can_ exist. You simply have no objective definition for the base class(es) of `B`.

Comment: @MSalters, it's not that complicated, all I want is to make the generated class A is possible to extend while class B will benefit from the inheritance. If a colleague extends `class D: pulic A` which I don't know what D is, then this is not my problem to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

A common C++ solution is `freeFunction(A&)` instead of creating `class B`. Unlike pure OO languages, C++ has free functions which are not class members. Your `freeFunction_B(A&)` and your colleague's `freeFunction`_C(A&)` will not interfere.

Obviously this is not a solution when you need to add data members. In that case, there's another option. Leave open the base class:

```
template<typename BASE> class B : public BASE { 
  // ...
}
```

This allows both `B<A>` and `B<C<A>>`. Slight downside: `C<B<A>>` is not the same type as `B<C<A>>`, which is logical. The members have to be in a certain order in memory, and there are two choices.

(General advice: code generation and C++? That means templates)

Comment: Thanks for answering, the super class is not a certain class name, but a template, this idea seems inspired me. By the way, the generated class is more like a protobuf or aidl, I can't find a way just using C++ template.

Comment: @reavenisadesk: A super class by definition is a type, and not a template. It can of course be a _template instantiation_. That's actually what happens in my example: the super class of `B<C<A>>` is `C<A>`. I suspect that when you and your colleagues understand templates a bit better, it becomes obvious how to use them.

Comment: Thanks, I know what you mean and we understand template better than you thought. Templates is not the panacea and I think I have explained why not using template. You suspect hurts me.

Answer (score 0):

As doing a research for some times, I think the term "monkey patch" is the technology what I'm looking for, but it seems only can be implemented with languages which has the reflection feature.

Currently I use "has-a" extension in my code instead of "is-a" to avoid changing the generated code.